# django eccomerce prodcut name not showing in file

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am creating a new django eccomorce website now in product detail page here is my code

the problem is i cant see product name correct in html page problem with first()
when i use first then only product name showing but all products have same name i have 8 producs in my page eight product name same to first just like overwriting also i cant use for loop with first()

i will add some pics

[image]

urls.py

```
 path('collection/<str:cate_slug>/<str:prod_slug>',views.product_view,name="productview"),
```

views.py

```
def product_view(request,cate_slug,prod_slug):
    if (Category.objects.filter(slug=cate_slug, status=0)):
        if (Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0)):
            products = Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0).first()
            context = {'products':products}
        else:
            messages.error(request,"no such product found")
            return redirect("collection")
    else:
        messages.error(request,"no such category found")
        return redirect("collection")
    
    return render(request,"product_view.html",context)
```

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    product_image = models.ImageField( upload_to=get_image,null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False)
    original_price = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    selling_price = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text="0=default , 1=Hidden")
    trending = models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text="0=default , 1=Trending")
    meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    meta_keyword = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=400,null=False,blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

productview.html

```
{% block content %}

 <h1>{{ products.product_name }} </h1>
 



{% endblock %}
```

i just want correct product name for every category i stucked here in morning helping are appreciated thank you all for helping till now

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop through your produckts:

```
{% for product in products %}
  <h1>{{ product.product_name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

view:

```
def product_view(request,cate_slug,prod_slug):
    if (Category.objects.filter(slug=cate_slug, status=0).exists()):
        if (Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0).exists()):
            products = Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0)
            context = {'products':products}
        else:
            messages.error(request,"no such product found")
            return redirect("collection")
    else:
        messages.error(request,"no such category found")
        return redirect("collection")
    
    return render(request,"product_view.html",context)
```

Note that usually the model name is singular, so it should be `class Products(models.Model):`

Comment: HI when i loop like this it shows products is not iterable when i remove first() function in my views.py then loop working but the problem is product name is same to all products i have 8 products 8 products have the same name. first product name is repeting to all other products name all details everything

Comment: also when i use for loop it displying all product names to all i mean 8 product name is repeting all products page not individual any one can find the bug ?

Comment: I also posted a slithly different view, if that doesn't work I'm not understaing what you're saying

Comment: thank you for ur support brother i fixed that its because of same slun name problem brother